# MongoDB Comparison query Object Array Operators

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose that there is the applicants collection in a MongoDB database with these documents:

```
[
{
    name: "Tom Hanks",
    age: 42,
    email: "tom.hanks@example.com"
    job:{
      "data engineer": 7,
      "professor": 3
  }
},
{
    name: "Ken Smith",
    age: 36,
    email: "ken.smith@example.com"
    job:{
      "electronics engineer" : 10,
      "database administrator" : 5
  }
}
]
```

I want to write a query that retrieves the applicants who have some experience in the **database field.**

**Tried:** `db.applications.find({ 'job': { $all: [ '.data.'] } })`
However it's not working.
Can someone help, please.

Comment: Using any data as field names is widely considered a MongoDB anti-pattern.  Using data as field names leads to future query pains.  You might consider a different data model - something like `"jobs": [{"title": "data engineer", "level": 7}, {"title": "professor", "level": 3}]`.

Comment: ... using the different data model, the query would be simple, something like `db.collection.find({"jobs.title": {"$regex": "data" }})`.

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hs your input worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how efficient this is or if its what you're looking for, but you can have a go at expanding the object to an array and then regex matching on each field using the [$objectToArray operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and then regex matching on the keys

```
  {
    $project: {
      jobMatch: {
        $objectToArray: "$job"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "jobMatch.k": {
        $regex: "data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can go deeper and add a value match by doing values greater than a certain number with $and, let me know if you found it useful